# How many random samples of a set of N values are needed for a 95% confidence in what N is?

Tags: sampling

Given I have a set of values N, where N is unknown to me. I can make requests for one sample at a time, which is selected randomly for me. As I request more samples, I see more and more values which I have seen before, and new values become more rare. How many do I need to request before I can be 95% confident that I know what N is?

Comment: Is there an ordering to the items, ie, the [german tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem), or are we just estimating the size of an unknown population?

Comment: Is $N$ a finite set of distinct values? If so, this is the famous coupon collectors problem, see for instance  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/estimating-n-in-coupon-collectors-problem

Comment: "How many do I need to request before I can be 95% confident that I know what N is?" I take it by this you mean you are 95% confident that it is a *particular* value, rather than that you are taking a 95% confidence interval?

Comment: There is no ordering, there are N distinct values, but I don't know what N is. It does appear to be the variation of the coupon collectors problem named [the fortune cookie message problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/estimating-n-in-coupon-collectors-problem). In [my specific case](http://blog.alexellis.io/april-1st-node-js-vs-bash/), I'm trying to gather the names of a servers behind a load balancer, which I am assuming randomly chooses servers for my requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the fortune cookie message problem as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/estimating-n-in-coupon-collectors-problem).
Thanks to kjetil for pointing me in that direction!