# How to get an estimator from this heuristic argument?

Tags: estimation, estimators

In the answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506622/how-much-of-the-big-picture-have-i-seen-already-problem), a practical solution was suggested for:

> Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $X_i \sim \mathcal{U}\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ (discrete uniform distribution). The parameter $n$ is unknown.
>   Let $U$ be the number of *unique* values seen in the sequence. Given $k$ and $U$, how to estimate $n$?

thanks to:

$$E(U) = n\left(1-\left(1- \frac1n\right)^k\right)$$

it "seems a good idea", given a value $u$ and a value $k$ to choose an estimator $\hat n$ of $n$ as the real root $> 1$ of the equation $x\left(1-\left(1- \frac1x\right)^k\right) - u = 0.$

How to turn this "seems a good idea" argument into a real probabilistic/statistic argument, i.e. how to create a rigourously defined estimator (using Estimation theory in Statistics) from this?

Additionally, how could we create a 95% confidence interval from this?

Note: I already read [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87880/102252) and the article from W. Esty (*Ann. Statist.*, 1983) but this needs extra information like the number of items seens once or twice, which I don't want to use.

Comment: This is basically a method of moments estimator, no?

Comment: @tchakravarty can you explain how this would work?